# Compile Rust Code properly for bare-metal ARM as static lib and as binary for x86_64?

Tags: c, rust, arm, embedded

What I want to do:
I have a piece of Rustcode, that I want to build

- as static lib for bare-metal ARM so it can be linked to an existing c program, AND
- as executable for x86_64, so I can develop, unittest, etc.

I can do both, but unfortunately I have to change each time the Cargo.toml.

main.rs

```rust
use foobar::foo::Bar;

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar::new();
    let ret = bar.do_something();

    //  ...
}
```

lib.rs

```rust
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]
#![cfg_attr(feature = "EMBEDDED", no_std)]

#[cfg(feature = "EMBEDDED")]
use core::intrinsics;

#[cfg(feature = "EMBEDDED")]
use core::panic::PanicInfo;

#[cfg(feature = "EMBEDDED")]
#[panic_handler]
fn panic(_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    unsafe { intrinsics::abort() }
}

#[cfg(not(feature = "EMBEDDED"))]
pub mod foo;
```

foo.rs

```rust
pub struct Bar;

impl Bar {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Bar{}
    }

    pub fn do_something(&self) -> u32 {
        42
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn call_from_c_prog() -> u32 {
    let bar = Bar::new();

    bar.do_something()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn foo_test() {
        let bar = Bar::new();
        let ret = bar.do_something();

        assert_eq!(ret, 42);
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foobar"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["..."]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]

#[[bin]]
#name = "foobar"
#path = "src/main.rs"
#test = true
#bench = false

[lib]
name = "foobar"
path = "src/lib.rs"
crate-type = ["staticlib"] # Creates static lib
#crate-type = ["cdylib"] # Creates synamic lib

[features]
default = []
EMBEDDED = []
```

With this Cargo.toml, I can build the code as static lib by running cargo

```
cargo build --lib --release --features EMBEDDED --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf
```

But when I try to build that code for x86_64 with

```
cargo test --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `foobar`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use foobar::foo::Bar;
  |     ^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `foobar`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `Bar`
 --> src/main.rs:4:15
  |
4 |     let bar = Bar::new();
  |               ^^^ use of undeclared type or module `Bar`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

I get the same error, when enable both sections ([[bin]] + [lib]).

So, when I change now the Cargo.toml to

```
[[bin]]
name = "foobar"
path = "src/main.rs"
test = true
bench = false


#[lib]
#name = "foobar"
#path = "src/lib.rs"
#crate-type = ["staticlib"] # Creates static lib
##crate-type = ["cdylib"] # Creates synamic lib
```

I can build and run the code with

```
cargo test --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

But if run now

```
cargo build --lib --release --features EMBEDDED --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf
```

I get an .rlib which is obvious since the section is commented out.

So, my question is now:
How can I do both things, without changing the Cargo.toml every time? I couldn't find a proper way yet.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html):

> --manifest-path PATH
>
> Path to the Cargo.toml file. By default, Cargo searches for the Cargo.toml file in the current directory or any parent directory.

Just have two `Cargo.toml` files and use `--manifest-path` to specify the manifest file. Also use `--target-dir` different for both builds, to build both at the same time.